assert failed: xQueueGenericSend queue.c:873 on esp32 with pn532 and sd card reader
I try to use pn532 on I2C and sd reader on spi. When I tested pn532 alone, it worked very well. But when I make these devices work together, ESP32 will report an error and force a restart:
    assert failed: xQueueGenericSend queue.c:873 (!( ( pvItemToQueue == ((void *)0) ) && ( pxQueue->uxItemSize != ( UBaseType_t ) 0U ) ))
This fault is always occur after nfc.readPassiveTargetID.
This is my code:
    #include <Wire.h>
    #include <PN532_I2C.h>
    #include <PN532.h>
    #include <NfcAdapter.h>
    #include <WiFi.h>
    #include <WiFiUdp.h>
    #include <NTPClient.h>
    #include <FS.h>
    #include <SD.h>
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <string.h>

    const char *ssid = "........";
    const char *password = "********";
    WiFiUDP ntpUDP;
    NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP, "ntp.aliyun.com", 3600 * 8, 60000);

    PN532_I2C pn532i2c(Wire);
    PN532 nfc(pn532i2c);

    File fRace;
    char RaceFileName[30];
    void appendFile(fs::FS &fs, const char *path, const char *message);

    SemaphoreHandle_t nfcMutex;
    SemaphoreHandle_t sdMutex;

    void loop_task(void *pvParameters) {
      while (true) {
        myloop();
        vTaskDelay(10 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
      }
    }

    void setup(void) {
      nfcMutex = xSemaphoreCreateMutex();
      sdMutex = xSemaphoreCreateMutex();

      Serial.begin(115200);
      Serial.println("Hello!");


      Serial.print("Connecting to ");
      Serial.print(ssid);
      WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
      }
      Serial.println("Connect success.");
      timeClient.begin();


      Serial.println("SD&File begin.");
      if (!SD.begin()) {
        Serial.println("Card Mount Failed");
        return;
      }
      uint8_t cardType = SD.cardType();
      if (cardType == CARD_NONE) {
        Serial.println("No SD card attached");
        return;
      }
      Serial.print("SD Card Type: ");
      if (cardType == CARD_MMC) {
        Serial.println("MMC");
      } else if (cardType == CARD_SD) {
        Serial.println("SDSC");
      } else if (cardType == CARD_SDHC) {
        Serial.println("SDHC");
      } else {
        Serial.println("UNKNOWN");
      }
      uint64_t cardSize = SD.cardSize() / (1024 * 1024);
      Serial.printf("SD Card Size: %lluMB\n", cardSize);


      timeClient.update();
      sprintf(RaceFileName, "/race%lu.csv", timeClient.getEpochTime() / 10000);
      Serial.println(timeClient.getEpochTime(), DEC);
      fRace = SD.open(RaceFileName, FILE_APPEND);
      if (!fRace) {
        fRace = SD.open(RaceFileName, FILE_WRITE);
        fRace.print("");
      }
      fRace.close();


      Serial.println("NFC begin.");
      nfc.begin();
      uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
      if (!versiondata) {
        Serial.print("Didn't find PN53x board");
        while (1)
          ;  // halt
      }
      Serial.print("Found chip PN5");
      Serial.println((versiondata >> 24) & 0xFF, HEX);
      Serial.print("Firmware ver. ");
      Serial.print((versiondata >> 16) & 0xFF, DEC);
      Serial.print('.');
      Serial.println((versiondata >> 8) & 0xFF, DEC);
      nfc.setPassiveActivationRetries(0xFF);
      nfc.SAMConfig();

      xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(loop_task, "loop_task", 4096, NULL, 1, NULL, 0);
    }

    void loop(void) {}

    void myloop(void) {
      boolean success;
      uint8_t uid[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };  // Buffer to store the returned UID
      uint8_t uidLength;
      char tmp[25] = { 0 };

      // Wait for an ISO14443A type cards (Mifare, etc.).  When one is found
      // 'uid' will be populated with the UID, and uidLength will indicate
      // if the uid is 4 bytes (Mifare Classic) or 7 bytes (Mifare Ultralight)
      Serial.println("Waiting for an ISO14443A card");
      delay(200);
      if (xSemaphoreTake(nfcMutex, portMAX_DELAY) == pdTRUE) {
        success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, &uid[0], &uidLength);
        xSemaphoreGive(nfcMutex);
      }
      if (success) {
        //timeClient.update();
        //Serial.println("Found a card!");
        //Serial.print("UID Length: ");
        //Serial.print(uidLength, DEC);
        //Serial.println(" bytes");
        //Serial.print("UID Value: ");
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < uidLength; i++) {
          Serial.print(" 0x");
          Serial.print(uid[i], HEX);
        }
        Serial.println("");
        sprintf(tmp, "%lu,%lu", *(unsigned long *)uid, timeClient.getEpochTime());
        if (xSemaphoreTake(sdMutex, portMAX_DELAY) == pdTRUE) {
          appendFile(SD, RaceFileName, tmp);
          xSemaphoreGive(sdMutex);
        }
        // Wait 1 second before continuing
      } else {
        // PN532 probably timed out waiting for a card
        Serial.println("Timed out waiting for a card");
      }
        delay(1000);
    }

    void appendFile(fs::FS &fs, const char *path, const char *message) {
      Serial.printf("Appending to file: %s\n", path);

      File file = fs.open(path, FILE_APPEND);
      if (!file) {
        Serial.println("Failed to open file for appending");
        return;
      }
      if (file.print(message)) {
        Serial.println("Message appended");
      } else {
        Serial.println("Append failed");
      }
      file.close();
    }

I try to add mutex and bind the loop function to core0, but none of them can solve the problem.

Never use delay() in your FreeRTos Task. I didn't read the rest.

Why did you create a new task that does what loop() does instead of just using loop()?

@romkey I try to bind this task to a core because I found some information mentioned that i2c task needs to start and end on the same core otherwise it may cause a error like this.

I'm not even completely sure what you mean by that, but you absolutely do not need to worry about that with this kind of program. Consider also the tens of thousands of Arduino programs using I2C running on an ESP32 that don't do that and work perfectly well. All you've done by doing that is add needless complexity and new ways to fail to your program.
